# rmarkdown include TOC

Tags: r-markdown, pandoc

I am writing `rmarkdown` and am exporting to `odt` and to `html`.  I can get a TOC in the generated `html` and I can get a TOC in the generated `odt`, but I cannot get a TOC in both simultaneously, as the code seems mutually exclusive.

How can I have a TOC generated from the same `Rmd` file in both, `odt` and `html`?

Here is how I get the TOC in `odt`:

```
---
title: Test TOC
toc: yes
toc-title: TOC
output:
  odt_document:
    keep_md: true
  html_document:
    number_sections: true
---

# Just a test document
With some text
```

Here is how I get the TOC in `html`:

```
---
title: Test TOC
output:
  odt_document:
    keep_md: true
  html_document:
    toc: yes
    toc-title: TOC
    number_sections: true
---

# Just a test document
With some text
```

If I combine the two, I get 'yes' as TOC in `html`.

I am using `rmarkdown 1.12` and `pandoc-2.7.3`

Answer (score 0):

Posting a work-around here.  But I am still interested in a better answer.

As a work-around I have renamed `toc` as `odt-toc` and `toc-title` as `odt-toc-title` in the `odt` template.

In more detail I use this `Rmd` file:

```
---
title: Test TOC
odt-toc: yes
odt-toc-title: TOC
output:
  odt_document:
    keep_md: true
  html_document:
    toc: yes
    toc-title: TOC
    number_sections: true
---

# Just a test document
With some text
```

with a modified version of the  [default odt-template](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/blob/master/default.opendocument) where I have replaced

```
$if(toc)$
```

by

```
$if(odt-toc)$
```

and

```
<text:index-title-template text:style-name="Contents_20_Heading">$toc-title$</text:index-title-template>
```

by

```
<text:index-title-template text:style-name="Contents_20_Heading">$odt-toc-title$</text:index-title-template>
```